# CSS: Image within image pops out when window resized

Tags: html, css

I am building really my first site. It will be for a comic book my friend and I are making. I am building it with Flask/HTML/CSS/etc and so far pretty good! I am decent at all these tools except for CSS.

On a subset of pages, the user can access an individual character's page. Each page will display an icon of the character in the top right of the window. I added some code to also randomly choose a fun picture frame to wrap around the image in question (this frame is also an image).

My issue is: When I resize the screen everything is OK until the window gets too small, then the icon-image pops out of the frame-image.

Here is my HTML code (note with Jinja2),

```
        <div class="frame">
            <img id="frm" src="/static/frames/Frame_{{randomInt}}.png" alt="Frame_{{randomInt}}" width="200" height="200"/>
            <img id="icon" src="/static/{{character}}_head.png" alt="Pic of {{character}}" width="150" height="150"/>
        </div>
```

Here is my CSS,

```
#frm{
    position: fixed;
}

#icon{
    margin:25px 0px 0px 25px;
    position: relative;
}
```

As I just mentioned, I am not very good at CSS...Just more of a drag and drop from W3 until I get it.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NmXuJuhXCkn8V00BARt3-pXMwiICwF_S/view?usp=sharing) is a Google drive link to a video of what is happening so you can get a bit more context. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the parent element, **.frame** to a fixed position, not the **#frm**. Then you can place the `#icon` using `position: absolute`.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.frame {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}

#icon {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <img id="frm" src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="Frame_{{randomInt}}" width="200" height="200" />
  <img id="icon" src="https://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="Pic of {{character}}" width="150" height="150" />
</div>
<h1>Some text that resulted in the images breaking when resized too small</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to have one image as a frame, and other inside it.

To achieve this, you may remove the first  tag. And add the image as background to css class "frame". As frame is the parent class, it will always contain the icon in it.

Something like this:

```
 <div class="frame">
        <img id="icon" src="/static/{{character}}_head.png" alt="Pic of {{character}}" width="150" height="150"/>
 </div>
```

And CSS will be:

```
.frame{
    position: fixed; 
    background:url("/static/frames/Frame_{{randomInt}}.png");
    background-size: 200px 200px;
 }
#icon{
   margin:25px 0px 0px 25px;
   position: relative;
 }
```

Comment: Note: This will abolish accessibility of the frame image, because background images cannot have alt text.